# Gathering entries in a matrix based on a matrix of column indices (tensorflow/numpy)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, pytorch

**A little example to demonstrate what I need**

I have a question about gathering in tensorflow. Let's say I have a tensor of values (that I care about for some reason):

```
test1 = tf.round(5*tf.random.uniform(shape=(2,3)))
```

which gives me this output:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 1., 2.],
       [4., 5., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```

and I also have a tensor of indices column indices that I want to pick out on every row:

```
test_ind = tf.constant([[0,1,0,0,1],
                        [0,1,1,1,0]], dtype=tf.int64)
```

I want to gather this so that from the first row (0th row), I pick out items in column 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, and same for the second row.

So the output for this example should be:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 5), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [4., 5., 5., 5., 4.]], dtype=float32)>
```

**My attempt**

So I figured out a way to do this in general, I wrote the following function gather_matrix_indices() that will take in a tensor of values and a tensor of indices and do exactly what I specified above.

```
def gather_matrix_indices(input_arr, index_arr):
    row, _ = input_arr.shape
    
    li = []
    
    for i in range(row):
        li.append(tf.expand_dims(tf.gather(params=input_arr[i], indices=index_arr[i]), axis=0))
        
    return tf.concat(li, axis=0)
```

**My Question**

I'm just wondering, is there a way to do this using ONLY tensorflow or numpy methods? The only solution I could come up with is writing my own function that iterates through every row and gathers indices for all columns in that row. I have not had runtime issues yet but I would much rather utilize built-in tensorflow or numpy methods when possible. I've tried tf.gather before too, but I don't know if this particular case is possible with any combination of tf.gather and tf.gather_nd. If anyone has a suggestion, I would greatly appreciate it.

**Edit (08/18/22)**

I would like to add an edit that in PyTorch, calling `torch.gather()` and setting `dim=1` in the arguments will do EXACTLY what I wanted in this question. So if you're familiar with both libraries, and you really need this functionality, `torch.gather()` can do this out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`gather_nd()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) for this. It can look a bit tricky to get this working. Let me try to explain this with shapes.

We got `test1 -> [2, 3]` and `test_ind_col_ind -> [2, 5]`. `test_ind_col_ind` has only column indices, but you also need row indices to use `gather_nd()`. To use `gather_nd()` with a `[2,3]` tensor, we need to create a `test_ind -> [2, 5, 2]` sized tensor. The inner most dimension of this new `test_ind` correspond to individual indices you want to index from `test1`. Here we have the `inner most dimension = 2` in the format `(<row index>, <col index>)`. In other words, looking at the shape of `test_ind`,

```
[ 2 , 5 , 2 ]
    |     |
    V     |
  (2,5)   |       <- The size of the final tensor   
          V
         (2,)     <- The full index to a scalar in your input tensor
```

```
import tensorflow as tf

test1 = tf.round(5*tf.random.uniform(shape=(2,3)))
print(test1)

test_ind_col_ind = tf.constant([[0,1,0,0,1],
                        [0,1,1,1,0]], dtype=tf.int64)[:, :, tf.newaxis]

test_ind_row_ind = tf.repeat(tf.range(2, dtype=tf.int64)[:, tf.newaxis, tf.newaxis], 5, axis=1)

test_ind = tf.concat([test_ind_format, test_ind], axis=-1)

res = tf.gather_nd(indices=test_ind, params=test1)
```

Comment: Phenomenal answer and explanation. Couldn't upvote this enough if we were allowed to. I really like the fact that this is exclusively tensorflow code because I need to pass a tf.Variable() into this procedure, so all of the operations need to be traced while I'm running a training loop. I didn't have an issue with the for loop in my original solution, but I don't think a python method like .append gets traced properly inside a tf.function. Appreciate it